# IIS Reverse Proxy with OpenIdConnect going to wrong Identity provider

Tags: azure-active-directory, reverse-proxy, openid-connect, iis-8

**OpenIdConnect (Azure) Settings**

```
// COOKIES: Tells it to use cookies for authentication.
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
});

// OPEN-ID: Authenticate via Azure AD using OpenIdConnect.
//https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect/
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ClientId = ClientID,
    Authority = Authority,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = PostLogoutRedirectUri,
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
    {
        AuthenticationFailed = PrincipalService.OnAzureAuthenticationFailure,
        // REFERENCE: https://russellyoung.net/2015/09/05/mvc-role-based-authorization-with-azure-active-directory-aad/
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification) =>
        {
            var username = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Name.Split('#').LastOrDefault();
            Logger.Log(Level.Auth, "Azure login success! Username: '" + username + "'.");
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
    }
});
```

**ARR Url Rewrite Settings**

```
<rewrite>
    <outboundRules> 
        <preConditions> 
            <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1"> 
                <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" /> 
            </preCondition> 
        </preConditions> 
    </outboundRules>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Secondary Server" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(https?)://" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="https://qa2mobile.auntmillies.com/{R:1}" />
            <serverVariables>
            </serverVariables>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Problem**

Azure AD authentication works just fine normally, but once I setup a reverse-proxy it starts taking me to my own domain as if it's the identity provider.

e.g. `https://my.domain.com/<guid>/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<guid>&etc`

- From this point, if I manually change `my.domain.com` to `login.microsoftonline.com` it'll log me in and proceed to work normally.
- If I remove the reverse proxy and set the server up normally, it goes directly to `login.microsoftonline.com` instead of my domain.

What is causing this? I mean, obviously the reverse proxy, but how do I fix it without removing the reverse proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is causing this? I mean, obviously the reverse proxy, but how do I fix it without removing the reverse proxy?

As far as I know, if you use url rewirte rule in the web.config, it will rewrite all the request to the https://my.domain.com/ domain which is include the login.microsoftonline.com.

I suggest you could write a new rule which is used to match the /oauth2 request url to directly rediret to the login.microsoftonline.com instead of the https://my.domain.com/. Then it will work well.

More details, you could refer to below url rewrite rule.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="rule2" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="<talentid>/oauth2/(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/{R:0}" />
          </rule>
            <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://<domain>.com/{R:1}" />

            </rule>
        </rules>
        <outboundRules>

            <preConditions>
                <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                    <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                </preCondition>
            </preConditions>
        </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: You know, now that it's been said to me, it seems so obvious. Not sure why I wasn't realizing this before. Thank you very much!